# EXCEL lookup an a row / array based on a cell value

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I would like to look up a row (an array) based on the DATE value, such that an array of price value (instead of a single return if using VLOOKUP) is returned for a given DATE value. Below is the data

```
       Column A   Column B     Column C     Column D
Row1   DATE       Product A    Product B    Product C
Row2   1/1/2017        1            5            7
Row3   7/1/2017        3            6            5    
Row4   13/1/2017       2            8            3
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Lookup INDEX and SMALL multiple items.

Comment: I could not understand your question? Actually what you want to achieve?

Comment: I apologize if my question is unclear to you. I have re-written and expand my question in another post. Please follow the link below. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42604794/excel-lookup-minimum-value-with-multiple-criteria)

Answer (score 0):

So one way to do this would be to make the lookup row a relative value. So assuming that your sample data is on Sheet1 and the list of dates you are looking up against is on Sheet2 Col A with a header. I would first make the lookup range a named range so that Sheet1 Col A thru Col D is named something like "Data". Then in B2 place the below formula and copy it to over to Col D and then all the way down the list of dates.

```
=vlookup($A2,Data,Column(B1),False)
```

The $ for A2 allows it to always look at column A even when copying over the formula. The Column(B1) returns a value of 2 but when you copy that formula to the left it will change to Column(c1), Column(d1)... thus changing what column of data you want returned.

Comment: Thanks Chad for the answer, and appreciate your effort. Perhaps I did not make my question clear enough. I have re-written and expanded my question in another post. Please follow the link below, and I would highly appreciate your suggestion. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42604794/excel-lookup-minimum-value-with-multiple-criteria)