# EXCEL lookup minimum value with multiple criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I am having problem with coming up a formula to lookup the minimum value of a particular product at a particular date (Sheet 2, Column C), and returning the name of the shop in (Sheet 2, Column D).

**Sheet2**

[image: Sheet2]

The sample data set is shown below: 
**Sheet1**

[image: Sheet1]

I need a formula (for each of column C and D) that would allow me to copy down the row, and gives me the lowest value of a certain product at certain date.

My initial thought for Column D is an array formula with INDEX, MATCH and MINIFS.
However, I am not sure the formula for Column C. I was thinking about VLOOKUP but not sure how I should go with selecting the appropriate array of price of a given product.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you normalize your data to 4 columns - Product; Shop; Date: Value?  They don't have to be in that order but would be much easier to analyze.

Comment: Unfortunately, the data is set up in this way to record the price of each product from different shops through time

Comment: You should still normalize your data as suggested by Mark, you can then easily create a PivotTable in the exact format you have above and also do any other analysis and reporting that you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lowest value should work this way:

```
=MIN(IF(($I$1:$L$1=$B2)*($H$3:$H$13=$A2),$I$3:$L$13))
```

Where:
***Check picture for data references***

[image]

Here is solution to return shop in D column:

```
=INDEX($I$1:$L$26,2,MATCH(B2&C2,INDEX($I$1:$L$1&OFFSET($I$1:$L$1,MATCH($A2,$H$1:$H$26,0)-1,),,),0))
```

Comment: Thank you for the solutions. Very helpful :)